# Copiar información a la que apunta un const *char a un char

Tags: c++

Tengo una función que me devuelve un `const *char`, y quiero copiar la información que contiene en esa palabra a un `char` pero no se como hacerlo.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct Card
{
    int suit = 0;
    int number = 0;
};
char suits[][15] = { "diamantes","picas","corazones","treboles" };
Card boardCards[4];
Card boardCards2[4];
void ShowBoard();
const char *SuitToString(int suit);

int main( )
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      boardCards[i].suit = i;
      boardCards2[i].suit = i;
   }
   ShowBoard();
}

void ShowBoard()
{
    char suit[] = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        suit = SuitToString(boardCards[i].suit);
        printf("%2c",suit);
    }
}

const char *SuitToString(int suit)
{
    return suits[suit];
}
```

Espero que por pantalla salga un elemento del `char suits[][];` y para saber ese elemnto uso la función `SuitToString()` que me devuelve el puntero de la información que quiero mostrar por pantalla. Pero no se como coger ese puntero y copiarle la información a el `char suit` dentro de la funcion `ShowBoard()`.

Comment: espero que por pantalla salga un elemento del char suits[][]; y para saber ese elemnto uso la funcion SuitToString() que me devuelve el puntero de la infromacion que quiero mostrar por pantalla. pero no se como coger ese puntero y copiarle la informacion a el char suit dentro de la funcion ShowBoard()

Answer (score 1):

En C++ los arrays de tamaño fijo, como `char[]`, aunque se comportan como punteros, no son exactamente igual que los punteros.

Para empezar, un puntero puede apuntar a regiones de memoria diferentes, mientras que un array de tamaño fijo no. A consecuencia de esta restricción la siguiente línea no compilará:

```
char suit[] = " ";

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    suit = SuitToString(boardCards[i].suit); // <<--- AQUI
    printf("%2c",suit);
}
```

Es decir, a un puntero se le puede asignar un array de tamaño fijo pero la operación inversa no es válida:

```
char array[100];
char* ptr = array; // ok
array = ptr;       // ERROR
```

La solución es tan sencilla como actualizar `suit` a puntero:

```
char* suit;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    suit = SuitToString(boardCards[i].suit);
    printf("%2c",suit);
}
```

Aunque dado que no se usa fuera del bucle lo mejor es reducir su ámbito:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    char* suit = SuitToString(boardCards[i].suit);
    printf("%2c",suit);
}
```

Claro que todo este problema te lo habrías ahorrado al usar `std::string`. Al tener un nivel de abstracción mayor permite escribir un código un poco más natural:

```
std::string suits[] = { "diamantes","picas","corazones","treboles" };
void ShowBoard();
std::string SuitToString(int suit);

int main( )
{
   ShowBoard();
}

void ShowBoard()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
       std::string suit = SuitToString(boardCards[i].suit);
       std::cout << suit << '\n';
    }
}

std::string SuitToString(int suit)
{
    return suits[suit];
}
```